# Convert string to datenum

Tags: string, matlab, datetime

I have a date string in this format

```
20151201T011654
```

I am trying to use the function `datenum` like this but I get an error:

```
formatOut = 'yyyymmTHHMMss';
Time = datenum(TimeStr,formatOut)
```

I suspect my `formatOut` is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you forgot the days `dd` and second the `T` can't be handled, get rid of it:

```
TimeStr = '20151201T011654'
formatOut = 'yyyymmddHHMMss';
Time = datenum(strrep(TimeStr,'T',''),formatOut)
```